# Data safety form - deletion request mechanism field not found

Tags: android, google-play

I have to fill out URL (or some other text) based on this [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/04/giving-people-more-control-over-their-data.html) about how to delete your user account if your app enables it. The problem is that I can't find where to fill out this info.  
 
 It should be somewhere inside Data safety form - possibly on the second page of this form and 3rd option there (currently only yes/no option with no additional field). Can someone post screenshot or any info where to fill this out? 
 Thank you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play Store webpages was not updated. After few days this update went live.